# CSS- HTML Flexbox: how to add a style without creating an another box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As soon as I create a balise or a span around the word  "Lorem", it gets out of the blue column.
How to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Here is a picture, to show the situation[image]

I try to learn to make two column, with some styled element in it.
In the column of the left, I would like the world "Lorem appear" to appear in bold, and to stay inside the blue column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overwriting the background in the '*' selector, try adding a background to the span, like this:

```
.bigword {
  backgound-color: inherit !important
  //if it does not work
  backgound-color: blue !important 
}

and wrap the text in some tag: 
<p>
  <span class="bigword">
  lorem
  </span>
  text
</p>

and you must add the background to the 'p' tag

p {
  backgound-color: inherit !important
  //or
  backgound-color: blue !important
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It works (for the color), but what if, if I don't the "Lorem" to be outside of the text? It is supposed to be with the text, only difference, it has to be bold.

Comment: It works, so indeed the 'p' tag was missing and 'p' and 'span' both needed the background color..  Thanks you